# React native wait till Redux state is ready

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have my app like below

```
import store from "./redux/store";


     <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer >
          <DrawerNavigator />
        </NavigationContainer>
      </Provider>
```

I am using react tool kit to persist my state , In my main component DrawerNavigator my state of loggedin is false for first few seconds and then turning into true.This problem is only in android , but not in ios , Can some one guide me  how to show splash screen or load DrawerNavigator only after my Redux states with persist is loaded fully.Thank you.

```
useEffect(() => {

console.log(loggedin);

  }, [loggedin]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Redux hooks!

1. Add the Redux hook from the **user**  reducer:

   `const {loggedin} = useSelector(state => state.user); //Replace to your reducer's name`
2. Control the render using that hook:

   ```
   { loggedin? //If loggedin is true, show the Splashscreen
     <SplasScreen />
   : 
     <NavigationContainer> // If loading is false, then show the drawer 
       <DrawerNavigator />
     </NavigationContainer>
   }
   </Provider>
   ```